# Delete questions to prevent down-votes

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Is it possible to delete a sensible but poorly asked question to prevent down-votes?

Comment: If you improve your poorly asked question, you might receive a couple of reverts.

Answer (score 3):

You can if it does not have any upvoted or accepted answers. But you risk a question ban if you do it more than once.

The better approach is to try to improve your question.

Comment: *more than once*, [citation-needed]

Comment: @AmitJoki: The algorithm of the ban is secret. So there is no concrete post for this. But it is commonly known that deleted post works towards the ban.